# Highchart tooltips formatter issue

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

[image]
I am using the config below to show the tooltips:

```
    tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{point.y}'
        },
```

the data is like:

```
data: Array(4)
0: {name: "RF_test_93219167", y: 1274958}
1: {name: "RF_test_26400097", y: 1274958}
2: {name: "RF_test_50328208", y: 1274958}
3: {name: "RF_test_73758432", y: 1274958}
```

and the tooltips still shows the Brand key in front of the value. and I don't want it to be bold or formatted, just show 1274958. just want it simple, and I don't want a dot in front of the value either. how can I achieve it?

Comment: Hi @jjzjx118_2, You probably configured the tooltip in a wrong place. Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/hyt1pgx4/ - everything works as it should.

Comment: yes, but I don't want it been formatted as 1 274 985 , I want it displayed as 1274985

Comment: You can change the default `thousandsSep` property. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1v7f5yrn/

Comment: this works for me, thanks @ppotaczek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    tooltip: {
    formatter: function () {
        return  this.point.name + ':' +this.y;
    }
},
```

use this instead of **pointFormat** to achieve the same, you also add additional things needed on the tooltip using this method.